# Opencart url issue

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

Here is my site http://goo.gl/Tsnqzr 
OC. 1.5.4.

There is contact url in green horizontal menu.
I added it myself in header.tpl:

```
<li><a href="http://italimporter.com/index.php?route=information/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

But I can't translate it in this case.
So I want change this link, as it is the footer. Second column from the left, first link from above:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
```

I did it but auto-translate doesn't work, unlike in the footer.

I try to change or delete same link in vq2-catalog_view_theme_bigshop_template_common_header.tpl on line 237

But in this case I get the error:

```
"Notice: Undefined variable: text_contact in /home/italimpo/domains/italimporter.com/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_bigshop_template_common_header.tpl on line 237"
```

So, how to make this link auto-translated?
What is the right way to add this url in header.tpl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the  following code to the following files

catalog/controller/common/header.php
open above file and paste below line in index() function.

$this->data['text_contact'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_contact');

second 
edit the language file of header.php  also.

Comment: please change this line $this->data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact');

Comment: There is no such line in catalog/controller/common/header.php. I added your code here after $this->data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle(); I did it after a added <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li> in catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/common/header.php and get the white blank homepage. What did I do wrong?

Comment: whereever you will see $this->data['some_name'] = $this->language->get in index.php or if you don't understand copy and paste your header.php here

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved this issue with the code: $this->data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact'); instead of your code ;)

Comment: If this answers helps you and solve your problem then click the tick sign below the answer which helps you to solve the problem and cloase your question

Answer (score 0):

Check your template header.php file..

Add the following into the index function

$this->data['text_contact'] = "Contact";//Whatever you need inside the " *** "

Make sure you should not add this line inside any foreach() loop or if() conditions

Better you can add after

$this->data['heading_title']

Comment: I added your code in catalog/controller/common/header.php after $this->data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle(); I did it after a added <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li> in catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/common/header.php and it doesn't work. Link is dead and not translated. What did I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

$this->data['text_contact'] = "Contact";//Whatever you need inside the " *** "

This code is only for Text view..

Please add another code.,

$this->data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact', 'SSL');

// It Will work

Comment: Same error. You can see right now. Your code was added in atalog/controller/common/header.php. Additionally the code <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li> was added in  in catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/common/header.php

Comment: "Notice: Undefined variable: text_contact in /home/italimpo/domains/italimporter.com/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_bigshop_template_common_header.tpl on line 237"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved this issue with the code: $this->data['text_contact'] = $this->language->get('text_contact'); instead of your code ;)